# How to sort list<string> in custom order

Tags: c#, list, sorting

Having a string like "CAATCCAAC" I am generating all kmers from it (k is variable but has to be less than string) doing:

```
        string dna = "CAATCCAAC";
        dna = dna.Replace("\n", "");
        int k = 5;
        List<string> kmerList = new List<string>();
        var r = new Regex(@"(.{" + k + @"})");
        while (dna.Length >= k)
        {
            Match m = r.Match(dna);
            //Console.WriteLine(m.ToString());
            kmerList.Add(m.ToString()); 
            dna = dna.Substring(1);
        }
        var sortedList = kmerList.OrderBy(i =>'A').
                        ThenBy(i => 'C').
                        ThenBy(i => 'G').
                        ThenBy(i => 'T').ToList();
        foreach (string result in sortedList) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

I want to sort result

```
 AATCC
 ATCCA
 CAATC
 CCAAC
 TCCAA
```

However I am getting

```
CAATC
AATCC
ATCCA
TCCAA
CCAAC
```

How can I sort elements so they are ordered first by 'A' then by 'C' then by 'G' and finally 'T' ?

I tried

```
var sortedList = kmerList.OrderBy(i =>'A').
                            ThenBy(i => 'C').
                            ThenBy(i => 'G').
                            ThenBy(i => 'T').ToList();
```

but that wouldn't work

I want the result like to be aplied for all string like

```
AAAA
AACG
ACCC
ACCG
ACCT
...

TTTT
```

Comment: So, by "custom" order you mean "alphabetical" order? :)

Comment: you don't need to order by character like so, just compare the strings.

Comment: This seems to me alphabetical order. But also you can write your own comparer class and using that in the sort method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to order in alphabetical order you can use:

```
List<string> sorted = kmerList.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

To get the reverse:

```
List<string> sorted = kmerList.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to sort a list in an alphabetical order,you should use the built-in Sort function:

```
kmerList.Sort();
```

Comment: and if it would be inverse order T->G->C->A?

Comment: `kmerList.Sort().Reverse()`

Answer (score 1):

There's a build-in sort function. Try kmerList.Sort()